# Unable to allocate multi APK from Google play store correctly

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Here is multi APK configuration in build.gradle

```
    APK_version_1 {
        versionCode 190
        buildConfigField 'String', 'PublisherID', '""'
        minSdkVersion 17
        splits {
            density {
                enable true
                exclude "ldpi", "mdpi", "hdpi", 'xxhdpi', 'xxxhdpi'
                compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
            }
        }
    }
    APK_version_2 {
        versionCode 200
        minSdkVersion 19
        buildConfigField 'String', 'PublisherID', '""'
    }
```

I found that in some cases where SDK version is above 18 it is unable to give the **APK_version_2** to that user, but from the configuration it should. It locates the first APK in that case. 
I am unable to figure out whats wrong with this.Can any one suggest any thing ?

Answer (score 2):

Before you enable advanced mode to publish multiple APKs for your application, you need to understand the [rules](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) that define how publishing multiple APKs works. Make sure that all APKs you publish for the same application must have the same package name and be signed with the same certificate key. Also, each APK must not exactly match the configuration support of another APK. It must declare slightly different support for at least one of the [supported Google Play filters](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SupportedFilters).

You may browse again this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html) and check if you don't miss anything. Hope this helps!

Comment: abielita, Thanks for the advice. I gone through all the doc u mentioned but unable to figure out the issue thats why i questioned it. Can u please look into the question again and suggest any thing i put in wrongly.